# onTouch does not get called for ListView child child

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am trying to do `ListView` reordering with drag and drop, and I'm using the DevBytes example as a base. `onTouch()` doesn't get called on my ListView when I touch the drag handle, that is, a child of one of the `ListView`'s children.

As this didn't work, on my `Adapter`'s `getView()`, I tried doing the following:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (view != null) {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        } else {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.store_list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(view);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        holder.storeName.setText(mShoppingLists.get(position).getName());
        holder.editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final FragmentManager manager = ((Activity) mContext).getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                ShoppingListEditFragment shoppingListEditFragment =
                        ShoppingListEditFragment.newInstance(mShoppingLists.get(position).getId());
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, shoppingListEditFragment, "shoppinglistedit");
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });

        holder.handle.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                ((DynamicListView) parent).onHandleLongClickListener(new DragEvent());
                return false;
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

This partially works, but as the touch listener only triggers for touches, and not for when the touch ends, this doesn't work properly. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2):

The touch listener is only giving you action_down events because you are returning false. If you return true you will also be sent corresponding action_move and action_up/action_cancel actions.

I can't remember which page of the documentation states this, otherwise I would link to it.